# JavaScript - Call nested function from inside function in the same object

Tags: javascript

Ok I have no idea how to title this correctly to be honest, but here is the thing: I have a js file with this structure:

```
var PageApp = function () {
    return {
        init: function () {
            this.DoSomeThing();
            this.DoSomeOtherThing();
        },

        DoSomeThing: function () {
            $("#someButton").click(function () {
                alert("in button click");
            });
            function A1() {
                alert("in A1");
            };
        },

        DoSomeOtherThing: function () {
           function B1() {
                alert("in B1");
            };
            function B2() {
                alert("in B2");
            };
        },
    };
}();

PageApp.init();
```

Now, how can I call B1() function from inside A1()? or from the button event handler inside DoSomeThing()?

Comment: It is impossible with that code

Comment: You'd have to bind it with the parent function context, and use arrow functions in each so you don't lose context.

Comment: @silencedogood must be a magical arrow function for that to work.

Comment: Seems like this would be better off as a class.

Comment: It's not really clear why you're embedding those functions so deep anyway...why is B1 private to DoSomeOtherThing, since there's no way to call it? Anyway, you could expose its result via an argument to DoSomeOtherThing, if there's no need to hide that function.